# SQL query to select only results having an exclusive set of related entities from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, sqlite

I have a relational DB with 2 tables, let's say `paintings` and `colors`. They are in a many-to-many relation via the pivot table, `color_painting`.

The "paintings" table:

```
id  name
---------------------
1   Lion and cubs
2   Sunset in Ontario
```

The "colors" table:

```
id  color
---------------------
1   grey
2   yellow
3   orange
```

The "color_painting" table:

```
painting_id  color_id
---------------------
1            1
1            2
2            1
2            2
2            3
```

So, paintings are linked to colors as follows:

"`Lion and cubs`" is linked to colors "`grey`" and "`yellow`"

"`Sunset in Ontario`" is linked to "`grey`", "`yellow`" and "`orange`"

How do I write an SQL query that selects paintings that have ONLY specific colors in them, and no other colors?

E.g. I want paintings that only have "grey" and "yellow". Thus, the query should return the "Lion and cubs" painting but NOT "Sunset", since "Sunset" also has "orange".

Is it possible to do with one query? (The SQL should run on MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL, and SQL Server dialects).

Comment: choose any one of MySQL, SQL Server & Postgresql, sqlite.

Comment: Are you really using all those products?`

Comment: Show us your current query attempt. And also the expected result (having the already specified table data.)

Comment: I'm writing a framework that should allow for replaceable storage engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that all desired colors are used, count how many of those colors are used:

```
SELECT *
FROM paintings
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM color_painting
       WHERE painting_id = paintings.id
         AND color_id IN (1, 2)
      ) = 2
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM color_painting
                  WHERE painting_id = paintings.id
                    AND color_id NOT IN (1, 2));
```

Comment: Looks like perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` to exclude paintings with different colors and the remaining paintings has to have 2 rows to correspond to your needs.

```
select p.id, p.name
from paintings p
join color_painting cp on p.id = cp.painting_id  
where p.id not in
    (
       select painting_id 
       from color_painting cp 
       join colors c on cp.color_id = c.id and c.color not in ('yellow','grey')
    )
group by p.id, p.name
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works perfectly, I'd accept both answers if I could, but I had to make a choice and I accepted the other one for a few small reasons: 
- "explain" reveals a shorter execution plan there, 3 steps against 4; 
- "exists" will stop after first match found, while "in" will have to pull the entire rowset;
- it appeared a few minutes earlier

Other than that, I really like the elegancy of "having" clause in your answer and I'll use that part of your answer